# separate a list inside a list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list as a result of an operation done using split().how do i convert this output  into single lists and write to a file

```
["['48999', '19:09:11', 'R', 'qp32']", "['49054', '00:24:42', 'R', 'qp32']", "['49151', '0', 'Q', 'batch']", "['49173', '332:05:4', 'R', 'qp128']", "['49174', '179:22:4', 'R', 'qp256']"]
```

the File output should be like this

```
48999 19:09:11 R qp32
49054 00:24:42 R qp32
49151 0 Q batch
```

and so on till all the entries of the list are entered into the file

EDIT:
      content is

```
['48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;19:09:11;R;qp32\n', '49054.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1850-01_2;mcbkss;00:24:42;R;qp32\n', '49151.tyrone-cluster;gic7_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch\n', '49173.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;332:05:4;R;qp128\n', '49174.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;179:22:4;R;qp256\n']

for item in [s.split(";") for s in content]:
parsed_data = [item[0].split(".")[0], item[3], item[4], item[5].strip()]
print >>f,parsed_data
```

After reading data from the file the output of the list would be

```
["['48999', '19:09:11', 'R', 'qp32']\n", "['49054', '00:24:42', 'R', 'qp32']\n", "['49151', '0', 'Q', 'batch']\n", "['49173', '332:05:4', 'R', 'qp128']\n", "['49174', '179:22:4', 'R', 'qp256']\n"]
```

Comment: That's not actually a nested list, it's just a list of strings.

Comment: Is your list really *nested* or is it just strings as indicated by your code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` and the `csv` module will get the output you require:

```
l =["['48999', '19:09:11', 'R', 'qp32']", "['49054', '00:24:42', 'R', 'qp32']", "['49151', '0', 'Q', 'batch']", "['49173', '332:05:4', 'R', 'qp128']", "['49174', '179:22:4', 'R', 'qp256']"]

from ast import literal_eval

import csv

with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter=" ")
    for row in l:
        wr.writerow(literal_eval(row))
```

Output:

```
48999 19:09:11 R qp32
49054 00:24:42 R qp32
49151 0 Q batch
49173 332:05:4 R qp128
49174 179:22:4 R qp256
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert your string elements to a list objects then write to file :

```
import ast
l=["['48999', '19:09:11', 'R', 'qp32']", "['49054', '00:24:42', 'R', 'qp32']", "['49151', '0', 'Q', 'batch']", "['49173', '332:05:4', 'R', 'qp128']", "['49174', '179:22:4', 'R', 'qp256']"]
with open('my_file.txt','w') as f:
     for li in [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in l]:
           f.write(' '.join(li)+'\n')
```

> my_file.txt :
>
> ```
> 48999 19:09:11 R qp32
> 49054 00:24:42 R qp32
> 49151 0 Q batch
> 49173 332:05:4 R qp128
> 49174 179:22:4 R qp256
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the options, you can also use the handy module [pyparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparser/0.2) for these types of parsing.